# How can I execute Inner Swingworker classes?

Tags: java, swing, inner-classes

I want execute ExampleSwingWorker1 from Main GUI. Main GUI class compile and doing some jFrame and DB operations and show main app screen to user. And I have another class for store all of my Swingworkers.

```
public class WorkerClass {
  public class ExampleSwingWorker1 extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {      
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            process1();
            process2();
            process3();
            process4();
            process5();
            process6();
            return null;
        }
        public void done() {
           Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }

}
```

Button Action in MainGui Class;

```
private void buttonRefreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

  WorkerClass.ExampleSwingWorker1 trying = new WorkerClass.ExampleSwingWorker1();   
}
```

I tried with the above methods for instantiating ExampleSwingWorker1 but it's not possible. [But this Oracle Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) offer this method for reach inner class.

Comment: I dont know is it working. When i type trying. list off avaliable actions of swingworker comes. But instantiating line still return errors. How is possbile ?

Comment: Cause you need an instance of `WorkerClass` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an instance of `WorkerClass` first

```
Workerclass worker = new WorkerClass();
WorkerClass.ExampleSwingWorker1 trying = worker.new ExampleSwingWorker1();
trying.execute();
```

Read more: [Inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)|[Nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Note: If it doesn't use WorkerClass instance method's think it to make it `static` then you don't need an instance of WorkerClass to create a `ExampleSwingWorker1` instance.

Note2: It's recommended that you add `@Override` annotation. Reasons? Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/94411/2415194)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Below code working for me. But i have some logical problem in Swingworker i think. Because i reference MainGUI class from there.

Comment: Then you have a bad design i guess.. MainGUI use WorkerClass and WorkerClass use MainGUI , they are too coupled

Comment: Yes. I must find a way using MainGUI methods and update MainGUI components from this SW without instance it.

Comment: @BlackWhite 1) You can pass the reference by parameter  `new ExampleSwingWorker(this)`  2) you can create your own `WorkerListener` then when `trying.addPropertyChangeListener(new MyListener)` where MyListener can/should be an inner class of `MainGUI` then there you can update. :D 3) Another possibility is using a kind of mediator that communicates between WorkerClass and MainGUI